# Redirecting www to non-www

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx, https, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from an HTTP site to an HTTPS site as well as all www traffic to the non-www site. My setup includes an nginx.conf file for the HTTP site which I've added a 301 redirect rule to:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name
        sub.domain.com
        www.sub.domain.com
       ;

    return 301 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
    ...
}
```

I also have an https nginx.ssl.conf file which looks something like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ...
}
```

With this setup, I'm able to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS but if I try to add a redirect in my nginx.ssl.conf file I receive a "too many redirects" error.

Any suggestions on how I can redirect everything to my HTTPs, non-www site?

Comment: What redirect do you add?

Comment: I tried adding the same redirect in my nginx.ssl.conf as my nginx.conf: "return 301 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;"

Comment: Please run `nginx -T` and then post complete config. You need to have the redirect inside listen 80 only, that is what you need for a http to https redirect. Not sure why you want the same thing outside the block

Comment: But how about the www to non-www redirect? I've got the HTTP to HTTPS redirect down, but the site still returns a 200 from the www subdomain.

Comment: Split your https block in two. One block with `www.sub.domain.com` and do a redirect in that. And the other block will keep the logic you have currently

Comment: Ah easy enough! Thanks, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your https block into two domains

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name
        sub.domain.com
        www.sub.domain.com
       ;

    return 301 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
    ...
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  www.sub.domain.com;
    return 301 https://sub.domain.com$request_uri;
    ssl on;
    ...
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name  sub.domain.com;

    ssl on;
    ...
}
```